# Comment-only script for Google docs

Tags: google-docs

I am trying to lock a file from edit permissions and only allow comments at a specific date and time. User list is long for a manual process.

Is there a way to write a script that will make a Google doc Comment Only and have that script run at a specific date and time?

I want a script similar to https://www.labnol.org/code/read-only-google-drive-file-201011 for readOnly but for Comment Only.